# Missing values after multiple imputation

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, mice

**Update**: It looks like I mispecified my prediction matrix. By setting the columns of covariates I did not want imputed to 0, the problem was solved. I had set other columns such as IDs to 0, but I was under the mistaken impression that using `method = ""` for columns used in imputation was analogous/sufficient. I've left the question up with this correction in and reduced the simulated data below  for clarity if anyone stumbles across this with similar issues.

I have a dataset I would like to use for multivariable Cox regression. There are some missing data and they are not MCAR. I’ve attempted to do multiple imputation with predictive mean matching for this data. Some facts about the data:

- 25,000 observations
- 10 variables of interest for regression
- 1,750 rows with at least one variable missing (7%). This is largely in one variable with 4% missing
- 150 rows have more than one variable missing

I have a prediction matrix with 17 variables. 8 variables do not have any missing data. I am trying to impute 6 variables, 3 are binary, 3 are ordinal. The issue I’ve run into is that even after imputation, there are 75 rows with missing data. These are cases with more than one missing element. Without more elements to help with imputation, I don’t believe these rows can be imputed.

I've used multiple imputation in the past, but I haven’t faced this problem before. Is it valid to perform the analysis with the multiple imputation and exclude those that still have missing data? Or would it be better to simply do complete case analysis?

I am using the `mice` package in R. The outcome is included as binary in the imputation model.

```r
library(mice)
set.seed(1)
n <- 25000

y <- sample(c(0,1), size = n, prob = c(0.8, 0.2), replace = T)

x1 <- sample(c(1:3, NA), size = n, prob = c(0.6, 0.35, 0.05, 0.004), replace = T)
x2 <- sample(c(0:3, NA), size = n, prob = c(0.65, 0.25, 0.06, 0.04, 0.0015), replace = T)

x3 <- sample(c(0,1, NA), size = n, prob = c(0.15, 0.85, 0.005), replace = T)
x4 <- sample(c(0,1, NA), size = n, prob = c(0.88, 0.11, 0.002), replace = T)
x5 <- rnorm(n, mean = 65, sd = 15)

id = "A"

mydat <- data.frame(id, y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)

predict_vars <- c("y", 
                  "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x4",  "x5")
miss_vars <- c("x1", "x2")

pred <- mice::make.predictorMatrix(mydat)
do_not_use <- which(!names(mydat) %in% predict_vars)
do_not_impute <- which(!names(mydat) %in% miss_vars)
pred[,c(do_not_use, do_not_impute)] <- 0
pred[do_not_use,] <- 0
meth <- mice::make.method(mydat)
meth[which(!names(mydat) %in% miss_vars)] <- ""


imp <- 
  mice::mice(mydat,
             predictorMatrix = pred, 
             meth = meth,
             seed = 1, 
             maxit = 5)

df <- complete(imp, 2)
colSums(is.na(df))
```

Comment: What multiple imputation software are you using?  Sounds like the software has a problem or needs an option selected that will make it cycle to take care of multiple missings on the same subject.  Also specify how you are coding the outcome variable for use in the imputation models.  It is necessary to include the outcome as an imputer.

Comment: Hi @FrankHarrell, thank you for your comments. I'm using the `mice` package in R. The outcome is included as binary in the imputation model. Is there a more appropriate way to specify a time to event outcome in imputation?

Comment: Check `mice` options.  It shouldn't result in `NA`s.  Imputation needs to use event times (and probably the censoring indicator) possibly transformed by the cumulative hazard function.  See [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2998703).